# Why am I getting index error exception error?

Tags: python

```
    try:

        # recheck this bank detail lookup, can optimize this

        # Known fact: as getting bank details and making refund is not in sync, we have bank_details against
        # one of the shipment id, so not sure of refund will go against specific bank details.
        # Current policy: taking latest one
        user_obj = self.session.query(User).filter_by(id=self.order_obj.user_id).one()
        current_shipment_id = self.shipment_id
        current_shipment_obj = self.session.query(Shipment).filter_by(id=current_shipment_id).one()
        prev_shipment_id = current_shipment_obj.previous_shipment_id
        bank_account_details = self.session.query(BankAccount).filter(
            BankAccount.affiliate_order_id==self.order_obj.affiliate_order_id,
            BankAccount.user_id==user_obj.mongo_user_id,
            BankAccount.shipment_id.in_([current_shipment_id, prev_shipment_id])
        ).order_by(desc('created_ts')).all()[0]  # IndexError

    except IndexError:
        logger.exception("Unable to process refund, as no bank details found")
```

{bag_id: 51156, current_awb_no: 'null', current_shipment_id: '16266090343871907281J', forward_awb_no: 'null', forward_shipment_id: 'null', invoice_no: 'null', jm_order_id: '16260961159105232A', payment_id: 51186}
exception
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Because this statement

```
self.session.query(BankAccount).filter(
        BankAccount.affiliate_order_id==self.order_obj.affiliate_order_id,
        BankAccount.user_id==user_obj.mongo_user_id,
        BankAccount.shipment_id.in_([current_shipment_id, prev_shipment_id])
    ).order_by(desc('created_ts')).all()
```

has length less than 1, and it's impossible to get the first element from an empty list.

Comment: Can you give a solution to resolve this issue

Comment: you should add if statement to check 

if len(bank_account_details) > 0:
  bank_account_details = bank_account_details[0]
else:
 print("there are no any bank account details for this user") # or raise some error or warning depends on your project logic